# Run code in specific time with telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to send message from my bot in specific time, in 7:00 every day, WITHOUT cron and stuff like that. How I can do it???

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")

bot.polling()
```

I can't do if by myself because of `bot.polling()`. This line just throw my program into the infinity loop, where i can't insert

```
if time() == specific time:
    send.message()
```

Please, help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `thread`, `datetime` and `time`.

```
import threading
import telebot
import time
import datetime

def message_timer():
     while 1:
         if str (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("% H")) == "7":
              bot.send_message(user_id, "Message")
              # 60*65 because it doesn't send the message continuously but only does it once
              time.sleep(60*65)


# Do some stuff ...

x = threading.Thread(target=message_timer)
x.start()

# Do some stuff ...
```